# Meu container com o SpringBoot está subindo antes do container com o MySQL terminar de subir

Tags: mysql, docker

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  marvel-api:
    build: my-api
    container_name: my-api
    depends_on:
      - my-api-bd
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  my-api-bd:
    build: my-api-bd
    restart: always
    container_name: my-api-bd
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    expose: 
      - 3306
```

Os containers começam a subir simultaneamente, onde o **my-api** solicita acesso ao banco antes mesmo dele terminar de subir, causando a exception: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)` existe uma forma nativa de um esperar o outro? Como podem ver, para paleativamente resolver o problema, eu usei o `restart: always` mas sinto que isso não é uma solução muito bonita...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um script para verificar se o serviço desejado já está rodando.
Eu utilizo o [wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for) um script compatível com imagens do alpine como base,
Utilizando juntamente com o `depends_on` você consegue controlar a ordem de inicialização dos serviços.

No exemplo abaixo, o serviço `web1` será executado após 11 segundos, como o serviço `web2` teoricamente depende dele estar executando, só será inicializado após o serviço `web1` estar executando normalmente.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web1:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        command: sh -c "sleep 11 && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        ports:
            - 81:80
        networks:
            - test

    web2:
        build: .
        command: sh -c './wait-for web1:80 -- nginx -g "daemon off;"'
        depends_on: 
            - web1
        ports:
            - 82:80
        networks:
            - test

networks:
    test:
```

Exemplo completo pode ser encontrado nesse repositório do [github](https://github.com/arkanjoms/docker-compose-wait-for)

Na [documentação oficial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) do docker-compose, ele também cita que o comando `depends_on` não garante que a aplicação dentro do serviço especificado esteja rodando, ele apenas garante que o serviço foi criado e até recomenda a utilização de scripts para controlar a inicialização de serviços que dependam de outros.

> Apenas pra efeito de conhecimento, na versão 2 do `docker-compose` era possível controlar a ordem por configuração no próprio `docker-compose.yml`, utilizando a configuração [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck) no serviço do banco de dados e utilizando uma `condition` no comando [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on) na configuração da api.

Answer (score 0):

Notei que você pode adicionou o argumento **depends_on** ao seu yaml no service **my-api** mas não resolveu o problema. O que parece estar acontecendo, o container espera o container de banco de dados ficar ativo, mas o processo do banco de dados não foi iniciado ainda. Você pode utilizar a seguinte estratégia:

```
restart: on-failure
```

Dessa forma o Docker irá tentar restartar sempre que encontrar um problema.