# applicacao springboot não conecta com mysql no ambiente docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, amazon-aws

Estou iniciando no mundo de containers, e ao tentar subir uma aplicação desenvolvida em SpringBoot com integração ao mysql no docker em um ec2 da aws, a aplicação não efetua a conexão com o mysql.

**Erros:**

```
...
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql_server
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  api-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-vol:

services:
  mysql_server:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes: 
      - mysql-vol:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ecommerce
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      - api-network

  api_ecommerce:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - api-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql_server
```

**application.properties:**

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql_server:3306/ecommerce
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**mysql no pom.xml:**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: já verificou se o container está iniciado e acessível? pode ser que sua aplicação tenha iniciado antes do mysql estar disponível e respondendo, o "depends_on" não garante que vai esperar o outro container estar 100% funcional para iniciar

Comment: @RicardoPontual a aplicacao ta subindo antes que o mysql, como eu posso garantir que suba o mysql primeiro?

Comment: tem alguns scripts que ficam tentando fechar um conexão com o servidor para validar isso, mas o ideal é sua aplicação ser resiliente a isso. Um boa ideia é, na inicialização do spring se não conseguir conectar, gerar uma pausa de sei lá 5s e tentar novamente, e ai sim dar erro, mas se fizer isso na aplicação não vai ter de se procupar com o compose dos containers

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Você está conseguindo conectar no banco com um client mysql normalmente?

Comment: @leandro.dev sim, conecta normalmente em um client mysql, o problema é que as vezes em rodar o docker-compose, a aplicacao é iniciado primeiro que o mysql, entao ocorre esse erro. entao tem que ficar rodando o docker-compose ate o mysql ser iniciado primeiro!

Comment: @cazzruan, você pode criar um *script* em *bash* para verificar se a conexão com o banco de dados está ativa; caso esteja, continua a execução do *script*; caso contrário, aguarda. [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/). Você pode usar o *script com nc* ou *wait-for-it*, *dockerize*, *wait-for* ou mesmo o *mysqladmin*.

Comment: @cazzruan nessa dúvida tem uma resposta que acho que se encaixa com sua dúvida https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445963/24201

Answer (score -2):

No depends_on do api_commerce, coloque assim:

```yml
depends_on:
      mysql_server:
        condition: service_healthy
```

No mysql_server, coloque:

```yml
       healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 20s
            retries: 10
```

Dessa maneira, você está dizendo:
`api_commerce` depende de `service_healthy` retornar ok do `mysql_server`.

O **ok** do mysql_server vai vir desse healthcheck que responde positivo se o serviço já tiver subido.

*<sub>Se der errado comente que reproduzo na minha máquina até conseguir a solução.</sub>*

Comment: Infelizmente nao resolveu, aparece outro erro e é referente a esses novos comandos.
`ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
services.api.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array`

Comment: Qual a versão do docker?

Comment: `Docker version 20.10+dfsg1, build 55c4c88`

Comment: Se não tiver resolvido ainda, poste como ficou após essa modificação. Pois assim conseguimos reproduzir.